# What is the meaning of "volume reduction unit"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> Clutter is the ponderous euphemism that turns a slum into a depressed socioeconomic area, garbage collectors into waste disposal personnel and the town dump into the volume reduction unit.
>   --*On Writing Well* by William Zinsser, page 13 (via [IVP - Andy Unedited](http://andyunedited.ivpress.com/2013/02/cut_the_clutter.php))

I couldn't understand the meaning of "volume reduction unit" in this sentence.

Comment: A unit for measuring reduction of volume.

Comment: That's not a "sentence" you've provided, it's a sentence fragment. Your question could be improved if you edited it, and provided a longer excerpt along with some information about where you found this. (See the "Provide as much context as possible" part of our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439) post.)

Comment: I provied the whole sentence.

Answer (score 3):

A **volume reduction unit** is machinery that **reduces** the volume of something, from my experience usually involving a liquid.

Reducing the volume of a **liquid** is usually achieved through **evaporation**.
Reducing the volume of a **solid** is achieved by **compaction**.
Reducing the volume of a **sound** can be achieved through **noise cancellation** or some method of **volume control**.

In your ***commented*** example, volume reduction of trash can be achieved by **compaction** and also **combustion**

Answer (score 2):

The author is talking about verbosity, or a desire to make what one writes sound more ponderous and meaningful or more "official". "Clutter" is his pejorative term for this practice.

He gives three nouns (slum, garbage collectors, and town dump) along with their verbose versions.

Another example: yesterday on the radio someone said "put him in a state of incarceration" when he could have said "incarcerate him" or even "put him in prison".

Comment: Right. And being an example of clutter, it is not surprising that "volume reduction unit" is not in common use. We are *not supposed* to understand it.